# convert my website to a sharepoint site

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am new to sharepoint online 2013.

I have a simple mapping application(webmap with html5/css/js (javascript/jquery) that I would like to move into a sharepoint subsite/master site available to my sharepoint users (that they must be logged in to see)

**How do I import the html5, css, and js to sharepoint as set up the page?**

It keeps trying to get me to use templates and I am not sure where to put these files for my site. I am using sharepoint online 2013 and sharepoint designer 2013.

Please help Thanks.

Comment: why you want to import your simple html5 site to sharepoint?

Comment: im thinking that because all my docs are in sharepoint I could host the private site there as well so my users will have one login to access and edit their docs as well as use the private site. Would sharepoint online 2013 be too slow? Im looking into hosting on amazon s3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get your site up and hosted inside SharePoint would be to rename all your .html files to .aspx and upload the entire thing into a document library including folders with your js and css files.

Your users would need to be logged in to see the pages and you would only need to modify your existing solution to change any .html links in the content to .aspx (I would just write a quick batch file to do this).

You can keep the exact format and structure you currently have so you don't need your supporting css and js to be in the Style Library, they can just be in the same document library in their own folders so your existing relative links will keep working.

Answer (score 0):

You can create normal web part pages/blank pages in "Site Pages" and copy your html design structure.All the scripts,css will need to be uploaded to "style library" of SharePoint site.Below is link to create web part pages using SharePoint designer.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-sharepoint-site-pages-HA101782505.aspx